# 3 step form using ajax that sends data from one step to the next

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm looking to redesign a 3 page form on my website.

**Currently**:

1. *page 1* gets some initial data from the user and is submitted by POST to page2
2. *page 2* uses this data to show only the appropriate form fields based on the
   initial data and is submitted by POST to page 3
3. *page 3* finally captures contact info before sending
   the form via ajax to show the result of a mysql query on the same
   page.

What I'd like to do is for the entire form to be on one page, with each step being submitted and the data sent to be used in the next step via ajax (along with some tidy jQuery slideUp slideDown action to hide & reveal steps) to create a more seamless experience. I've looked for a resource to demonstrate sending data between forms on the same page using ajax but I can't find anything and i'm stumped.

Any pointers would be very much appreciated!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ --- that's all what you need

Comment: Turns out I was over thinking it and don't need 3 ajax submissions at all. Thanks for your input - have posted my solution as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah I don't need 3 forms submitted by ajax, i've turned the entire page into 1 form and have a click event on progression to the second step that does what needs to be done with the data from step 1, with step 3 finally submitting the entire form using AJAX, perfect!

Answer (score 1):

There's an easy solution: use the [wicked gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked?view=asciicast).

Also see [webform to wizard](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/webform_to_wizard/)